# Sumo(0.17.1) undefined reference to Xerces(3.1.1)

Tags: makefile, xerces

I installed xerces lib(3.1.1) with:

> `$ ./configure`
> `$ make`
> `$ sudo make install`
> `$ ldconfig`

I try to install the sumo(0.17.1) with:

> `Me@maq:/usr/local/src/sumo-0.17.1$ ./configure --with-fox-includes=/usr/include/fox-1.6 \--with-gdal-includes=/usr/share/gdal --with-proj-libraries=/usr \--with-gdal-libraries=/home/Me/include --with-proj-gdal`
>
> `$ make`

Which returns:

> `$ ../utils/xml/libxml.a(SUMOSAXReader.o):SUMOSAXReader.cpp:function vtable for`
> `xercesc_2_7::XMLRefInfo: error: undefined reference to`
> `'xercesc_2_7::XMLRefInfo::getProtoType() const'`
>
> `$ collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> `$ make[3]: *** [netgenerate] Error 1`
>
> `$ make[3]: Leaving directory` /usr/local/src/sumo-0.17.1/src/netgen'`
>
> `$ make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1`
>
> `$ make[2]: Leaving directory` /usr/local/src/sumo-0.17.1/src'`
>
> `$ make[1]: *** [all] Error 2`
>
> `$ make[1]: Leaving directory` /usr/local/src/sumo-0.17.1/src'`
>
> `$ make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1`

What can I do to fix this errors?

Thanks.

Comment: Try specifying `--with-xerces=...` as argument to the `configure` script.

Comment: It solved the problem listed above, but another showed up: gl2ps.c:3126: error: undefined reference to 'glRenderMode'
(it have some of them)

Comment: It seems that fox is configured with openGL support disabled.  You need to `configure` fox with `--with-opengl=yes`, build & install it.  Refer to the newly installed fox while configuring sumo.

Comment: It installed, thanks for your help and your patience.